# Not able to use 'if x in list' using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `df.iterrows` to iterate through each member of a dataframe of four columns, which looks kind of like this:

```
A      B      C      D
----------------------
A     ABC      
B     ABD
C     ABE
D     ABC
E     BC
F     D
```

but only if the letter in column A is in a list that looks like:

```
slist = ['A', 'C', 'E']
```

My goal, is if any row has an A in column B, it'll mark column C with an X, and if it has a C, it'll mark column D with an X. If it has both, it'll mark both.

In the end, it would look like this:

```
A     C      D
---------------
A     X      X
C     X      -
E     -      X
```

So, my current code looks like this:

```
for index, x in df.iterrows():

    if x['A'] in slist:
        if 'A' in x['B'] and 'P' in x['B']:
            x['C'] = 'X'
            x['D'] = 'X'
        elif 'C' in x['B'] and 'A' not in x['B']:
            x['D'] = 'X'
        elif 'A' in x['B'] and 'C' not in x['B']:
            x['C'] = 'x'
    else:
        continue
```

but `if x['A'] in slist:` never works, and I always get columns C and D back completely blank.

What am I missing that is causing this to happen? I've had the same problem on other projects, but have worked a way around it. This time, it's necessary to use a list and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I'm confused about the contents of your frame.  DataFrames aren't really meant to support lists as elements.  Is that "ABC" a list, or a string?

Comment: Do you mean `slist = ['A', 'C', 'E']`?  The way you wrote it it's not clear what `slist['A', 'C', 'E']` means.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Messed that up, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would used vectorized string operations for this, in particular `str.contains` (see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": list("ABCDEF"), "B": "ABC ABD ABE ABC BC D".split()})
>>> df["C"] = df["B"].str.contains("A")
>>> df["D"] = df["B"].str.contains("C")
>>> df
   A    B      C      D
0  A  ABC   True   True
1  B  ABD   True  False
2  C  ABE   True  False
3  D  ABC   True   True
4  E   BC  False   True
5  F    D  False  False
```

and then impose the Xs if you really want:

```
>>> df.replace({True: "X", False: ""})
   A    B  C  D
0  A  ABC  X  X
1  B  ABD  X   
2  C  ABE  X   
3  D  ABC  X  X
4  E   BC     X
5  F    D
```

If you want to only do this for cases where A is in `{"A", "C", "E"}`, you can select only those rows using `isin`:

```
>>> slist = ["A", "C", "E"]
>>> df[df["A"].isin(slist)]
   A    B
0  A  ABC
2  C  ABE
4  E   BC
```

and then apply the above technique.  (I sometimes toss in a `reset_index(drop=True)`, but that's up to you.)

Comment: This is the way to go, but he wants to restrict the operation only to rows where column A has one of the values in his `slist`.

Comment: just and with a mask using ``isin`` (or just sub-select afterwards)

Comment: The comparisons are not the problem I'm having (not yet, anyway). It's getting `Column A` to find itself in the list to determine whether or not `Column B` should even be searched for the strings.

Comment: @PointXIV: as Jeff says, you can use `isin` to handle that part.

Comment: @DSM, saw it right after I posted that. Going to try it.

Comment: Yep, that all works. I'll have to go back and fix some of my older projects with `isin`, never seen that before. Thanks!